# SoftLayer Load Balancer Command Line API Disable / Enable Service

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to disable/enable a service using SoftLayer command line API on Python

The command

```
slcli lb service-edit local:690561 --enabled
```

gives following error.

> SoftLayerAPIError(SOAP-ENV:Server): Internal Error

whereas

```
slcli lb service-toggle local:690561
```

works as expected.

I need a way to turn on and off service (not toggle).

It appears there is not enough documentation for service-edit available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error is the Identifier, for this case your identifier must be like this:

> LoadBlancerId:ServiceID

So try this:

```
slcli lb service-edit 1111:222 --enabled

Note: replace the IDS
```

To see the services id in your load balancer you can run:

```
slcli lib detail local:1111

Note:replace 1111 with the id of the load balancer
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked. I wish error message was more informational in this case.